# Django, use QuerySet.values() to created nested aggregation

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Using Django's aggregation tools, I can use

```
Author.objects.values('country', 'name').annotate(average_rating=Avg('book__rating'))
```

To get a list of `{name: XX, country: XX, average_rating: XX}` dictionaries. Using the plain django api and no raw SQL, is there a way of creating nested representation like

```
[{country: XX, results: [{name: XX, average_rating: XX}..], ..}]
```

?

Comment: I don't think django would create anything like this. Maybe you need a for loop on the `values` result. Or you are not sure how to construct such a data structure?

Comment: I can do this no problem, just wondering if there's any native django solution that I'm missing:)